# request.getCookies() is always null

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, servlets, cookies

With reference my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311181/cookies-are-not-sent-to-the-server) I would like to indicate that the cookies are actually getting sent to the server.
Problem is that `request.getCookies()` always return null no matter what. I can only retrieve them as a String from the request header like this

```
String cookiesFromHeaderStr = request.getHeader("cookie");
```

I don't want to read them from the header because I will have to parse the string manually.

I am setting the cookie using Javascript as follows

```
document.cookie = "loc={\"lng\":0.111111,\"lat\":50.111111}, expires=Wed, 05 Oct 2016 16:22:11 GMT, path=/\""
```

Is there an obvious reason why the cookies won't actually be returned with `request.getCookies()`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not secure to set cookies from javascript.

I suggest you to create a filter which will set the cookies.

Read this discussion [Setting cookie from doFilter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566073/setting-cookie-from-dofilter-method)